# Why starts my referece of integer value in die Code with {0}?

Tags: python, int

Why is the code starting with {0} insteas of {1} ? I looked in the handbook of python how the format statement works.But i didn't find a explanation. All in all I'm not quite sure to get it solved but i think in python starts all wie 0. Like in a list = ["0","1","2"] the starting value referring with 0.

```
   # my  Version
   print "Geben sie eine Zahl ein"
   print "Diese Zahl muss über 0 sein"
   print()
   num1 = int(input("Geben Sie eine Nummer ein: "))
   num2 = int(input("Geben Sie eine Nummer ein: "))
   num3 = int(input("Geben Sie eine Nummer ein: "))
   ans = num1 + num2 + num3
   print ("The total of {0} + {1} + {2} is {3}.".format(num1,num2,num3,ans))
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for `format`?

Comment: No Karloy but i will do it  now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{0}` is replaced by the first argument to `format` (`num1`), `{1}` is replaced by the second argument (`num2`), `{2}` by the third (`num3`), and `{3}` by the fourth (`ans`). The numbers inside the `{}` use zero-based indexing, just like lists. It's similar to

```
lst = [num1, num2, num3, ans

# Not valid code
{0}, {1}, {2}, {3} = lst
# Neither is this
{0} = lst[0]
{1} = lst[1]
{2} = lst[2]
{3} = lst[3]
```